# Checking if authorized access on http get response

Tags: android, authentication, get, httprequest

I'm trying to check whether the user and password is correct. I'm consuming an API and here's my code :

```
 String username = user.getText().toString(), password = pass.getText().toString();

      String URL = "MyUrl";
      String authData = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
      httpget.setHeader("Authorization", authData); 
      HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                String s = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this,DriverLogin.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
        }
```

I've got no problem if the username and password is correct. My problem is when the user inputted an incorrect login credentials. I have a line there checking if entity is not null. As I observed, whether the login credentials is right or wrong it goes in this condition. When correct, it displays the details I need. When wrong, it displays a message that details are not authorize. I want to catch that message in order to say that login credentials is wrong. I thought that if the details is wrong, entity will be null. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: can you post logcat here?

Comment: No errors on my logcat though.

Comment: Could you please share your url?

Comment: https://test.landstarcapacityplus.com/MobileServices/api/Drivers/

Comment: I got this response while i tried to login to this <Error><Message>Authorization has been denied for this request.</Message></Error>.What is the format of response if it is a success?

Comment: I hope you can check for "Error" tag in the response which exist when there is an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [status code](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/StatusLine.html#getStatusCode%28%29) of the [HttpResponse](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html) against [error 401](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_401#4xx_Client_Error):

```
if(response.getStatusLine() != null &&
   response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 401) {
    // authentication is required and has failed or has not yet been provided
}
```